# How does DefaultIfEmpty() imply left outer join?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, linqpad

How does this:

```
from c in Contacts
join a in Addresses
on c.Address_ID equals a.Address_ID
into Temp
from d in Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c.First_Name.ToUpper().Contains("Pin".ToUpper())
select new { id = c.Contact_ID, value = (c.First_Name??"") + " " + (c.Last_Name??"") + " " + (c.Company_Name??""), FirstName = c.First_Name, LastName = c.Last_Name, AddressFull = d.Address_Full, Phone = c.Phone, Email = c.Email, CompanyName = c.Company_Name }
```

translate to this (using LinqPad)?

```
SELECT [t0].[Contact_ID] AS [id], ((((COALESCE([t0].[First_Name],@p1)) + @p2) + (COALESCE([t0].[Last_Name],@p3))) + @p4) + (COALESCE([t0].[Company_Name],@p5)) AS [value], [t0].[First_Name] AS [FirstName], [t0].[Last_Name] AS [LastName], [t1].[Address_Full] AS [AddressFull], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Email], [t0].[Company_Name] AS [CompanyName]
FROM [Contact] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Address_ID] = ([t1].[Address_ID])
WHERE UPPER([t0].[First_Name]) LIKE @p0
```

It seems that `Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()` == `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

What's the reasoning behind this syntax?  Can someone please eloquently explain why?

Comment: Click the "lambda" tab in Linqpad. The fluent-LINQ equivalent of the query will answer your question.

Comment: @GertArnold  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a magic incantation. You get the same semantics with pure LINQ to Objects. The `join into` is a left join already. It puts all matching items into a collection. There can be zero items or multiple.

`from d in Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()` would be an inner join because if there were no matching items we would drop the outer row. `DefaultIfEmpty` can now be used to add a "dummy null" to make this a left join.

This whole pattern is a little awkward but there's logic behind it.